# Fedora 17 doesn't detect some key-presses

Tags: fedora, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop

About 1 week ago, I installed MATE desktop (Gnome2 fork) because I wanted to use XMonad in gnome. So I am pretty sure this problem has something to do with MATE.

My keyboard is just a basic HP keyboard (US layout); it doesn't have any specialised media/audio keys. So I decided, that since I never use the <kbd>Alt_Gr</kbd>, <kbd>Super_L</kbd> and <kbd>Menu</kbd> keys (3 consecutive keys), I could get the desktop environment to use those effectively as 'media keys'. Until I switched to MATE, I had been using XFCE and this worked very nicely.

However now that I try to reconfigure this in MATE, I found that these 3 keys specifically are not detected by the keyboard-shortcuts-setup-utility-thing. I suspected maybe XFCE was blocking them or something, but resetting XFCE's shortcuts to defaults didn't fix it. I even tried manually editing the shortcuts in mateconftool-2 (gconf), without success.

I have not been able to detect these 3 keys in any way, and `dmesg` shows nothing of interest. The only way I *know* they are working is that borders in programs jump, or do something, whenever I press one of these keys.

Are there any other tests I can run, or other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `xev` and a custom keymap?

Comment: @jasonwryan I have tried `xev`, this is the output if I press Alt_Gr: http://pastebin.com/7r7ZBU8F The only detected KeyEvents are the keys I use to close windows

Comment: Is that the `Super_L` and `Shift_L`? See [the Extra Keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys) page on the Arch Wiki for some more suggestions...

Comment: @jasonwryan those are just regular shift and "Windows" keys. Every key is detected properly except the 3 I mentioned originally

Comment: You should check for scancodes for each of those keys; either with `showkey` or `dmesg` if `xev` isn't helping...

Comment: `showkey` is working: it gives key codes 100;126;127

Comment: Excellent: you can use those codes to create a custom keymap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this problem. [This page](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/) shows how to use xmodmap to remap a keycode to symbol, and since `showkey` lists these keys' keycodes, I can just do this:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 100=Alt_R'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 126=Super_R'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 127=Menu'
```

Problem solved, but I still don't understand what caused it.